# Why passing df column not work when user function contain boolean conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I pass pd Series (e.g. df column) to user function without Boolean conditions then it works, otherwise fall with

> error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Sorry, new to Python, so can't get why in one case it processes element-wise but in case of Boolean - like array.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['football', 'football', 
'tennis','tennis','tennis'],
                   'B' : ['MESSI', 'ROONEY', 'FEDERER','NADAL', 'FEDERER'],
                   'C' : [5,4,6,5,6],
                   'D' : np.random.randn(5),
                   'E' : [1,2,4,3,5],
                   'F' : [1,0,1,0,1]
                  })
def diffs(E, F):
    vals = E - F
    return vals
```

This work:

```
df.loc[:, 'asd'] =  pd.Series(diffs(df.loc[:,'E'],df.loc[:,'F']), 
index=df.index)
```

And this code fall:

```
def peak_rate(E, F):
    if E > 0:
        vals = 1
    else:
        vals = 0
    return vals

df.loc[:, 'asd'] =  pd.Series(peak_rate(df.loc[:,'E'],df.loc[:,'F']), 
index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because, in the first case, it's just subtraction and two arrays or series can be added/subtracted/multiplied and output will still be a series. You can't do that for greater than or less than equations. Here's an alternate solution:

```
def peak_rate(E, F):
    if E > F:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df.loc[:, 'asd'] =  pd.Series([peak_rate(df["E"][i],df["F"][i]) for i in range(len(df))], index=df.index)
```

Or you don't even need the function `peak_rate`. You can write it like below (I'm guessing you meant `E > F` instead of `E > 0` in `peak_rate`. In case it was `E > 0`, just replace `df["F"][i]` with `0`)

```
df.loc[:, 'asd'] =  pd.Series([int(df["E"][i]>df["F"][i]) for i in range(len(df))], index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

the line:

```
if E > 0:
```

`E` (a.k.a `df.loc[:,'E']`) is a [pd.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and checks whether it's greater then 0

you can't check a whole series if it's greater then 0

what you can do is to use:

```
if E.all() > 0:
```

maybe you got confused with `'E'` and `E`